# how i can complete the borderlines in following code?

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[h]
\center
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Parameters} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Controllers} \\\cmidrule{2-5}

  &dsPIC33FJ64MC204  & dsPIC33EV64GM104 & S32K & XMC1402  \\
 & (Microchip) & (Microchip) & (NXP) & (Infineon) \\

\hline
Architecture & 16 bit & 16bit & 32bit & 32 bit \\
\hline
Temperature Range & -40{\,\celsius } to +125{\,\celsius}  & -40{\,\celsius} to +150{\,\celsius} & -40{\,\celsius}  to +125{\,\celsius}& -40{\,\celsius}to +125{\,\celsius}\\
\hline
    Voltage range & 3.0V to 3.6V & 4.5V to 5.5V & 2.7V to 5.5V & 2.0V to 5.5V\\
    \hline
    CPU speed &40MHz & 40MHz & upto 112MHz & 48MHz\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{}CPU performance&-40{\,\celsius} to +125{\,\celsius} & -40{\,\celsius} to +150{\,\celsius} & & \\
     for high temperature &= 40MIPS &= 40MIPS & &\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{I/O pins} & 35pins out of 44pins &  35pins out of 44pins & & 34pins out of 48pins \\
    & & 53pins out of 64 pins & & 48pins out of 64pins\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Comparators}&upto 2 analog&upto 4 analog & & upto 4 analog\\
    &comparators&comparators& & compatators\\
    \hline
    PWM resolution & 25ns&7.14ns & & \\
    \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{}communication &2 UART &2 UART & communication &4 interface \\
       Interfaces&modules supports &modules supports & protocol  &  channels usable\\
        & LIN 2.0& LIN 2.0&emmulation for &  as UART \\
        & protocol& protocol&more LIN&and LIN\\
    \hline
    Typical MIPS/MHz &1MIPS/MHz& &1.25DMIPS/MHz&0.84DMIPS/MHz \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{} Price for & & & & \\
    QFN-44 & &100= 2.55\euro& &5k=1.46\euro\\
    QFN-64 & 100= 3.86\euro & 100=3.51\euro & &5k=1.92\euro\\
    \hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{Controller Comparison Table-1}
\end{table}
```

Comment: It should be `\cline{2-5}` instead of `\cmidrule{2-5}`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Please do not use `booktabs` in combination with `\hline`s and vertical bars. This is not supposed to be combined. You can use `\cline` instead of `\cmidrule` here or you do a pure `booktabs` approach which could look like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bit}{bit}
\DeclareSIUnit{\EUR}{\text{\euro}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{*{5}{l}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{3}{*}{Parameters} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Controllers} \\
        \cmidrule{2-5}      
        & dsPIC33FJ64MC204  & dsPIC33EV64GM104 & S32K & XMC1402  \\
        & (Microchip) & (Microchip) & (NXP) & (Infineon) \\     
        \midrule
        Architecture in \si{\bit} & $16$ & $16$ & $32$ & $32$ \\
        Temperature Range in \si{\celsius} & \numrange{-40}{125} & \numrange{-40}{150} & \numrange{-40}{125} & \numrange{-40}{125} \\
        Voltage range in \si{\volt} & \numrange{3.0}{3.6} & \numrange{4.5}{5.5} & \numrange{2.7}{5.5} & \numrange{2.0}{5.5} \\
        CPU speed in \si{\mega\hertz} &$40$ & $40$ & upto $112$ & $48$\\
        CPU performance in \si{\celsius} & \numrange{-40}{125} & \numrange{-40}{150} & & \\
        for high temperature & $= \SI{40}{MIPS}$ & $= \SI{40}{MIPS}$ & &\\
        \multirow{3}{*}{I/O pins} & 35 pins out of 44 pins &  35 pins out of 44 pins & & 34 pins out of 48 pins \\
        & & 53 pins out of 64 pins & & 48 pins out of 64 pins\\
        \multirow{2}{*}{Comparators}&upto 2 analog&upto 4 analog & & upto 4 analog\\
        & comparators & comparators & & compatators\\
        PWM resolution in \si{\nano\second} & $25$ & $7.14$ & & \\
        communication &2 UART &2 UART & communication &4 interface \\
        Interfaces&modules supports &modules supports & protocol  &  channels usable\\
        & LIN 2.0& LIN 2.0&emmulation for &  as UART \\
        & protocol& protocol&more LIN&and LIN\\
        Typical in \si{MIPS\per\mega\hertz} & $1$ & $1.25$  & $0.84$ \\
        Price for & & & & \\
        QFN-44 & & $100 = \SI{2.55}{\EUR}$ & & $5\text{k} = \SI{1.46}{\EUR}$ \\
        QFN-64 &  $100 = \SI{3.86}{\EUR}$ &  $100 = \SI{3.51}{\EUR}$ & & $5\text{k} = \SI{1.92}{\EUR}$ \\
        \bottomrule     
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Controller Comparison}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is just a starting point. The table does not fit as it is too wide, but I do not know your document class and general setup so I do not want to spend more time on this. Until now, the table is not very clear as you are using multirows in some places and in others, you don't. Try to keep consistent.

Answer (score 1):

As variant/supplement to nice LaRiFaRi answer ...

In preparation of answer I assume, that the page is A4 size with text margins of 25 mm. Since table is with standard fonts of 10 pt size is wider than page width, I use smaller in table `\footnoteseize` fonts and also reduce `\tabcolsep` from default `6pt` to `5pt`. With macro `\makecell` from the package with the same name I achieve more clear and logical (to my opinion, of course) table setting structure.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[range-phrase={\ to\ }]{siunitx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\DeclareSIUnit{\bit}{bit}
\DeclareSIUnit{\EUR}{\text{\euro}}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{l}}
    \toprule
\multirow{3}{*}{Parameters} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Controllers}       \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
    &   \makecell[l]{dsPIC33FJ64MC204\\ (Microchip)}      
            &   \makecell[l]{dsPIC33EV64GM104\\ (Microchip)}
                    &   \makecell[l]{S32K\\ (NXP)}
                            &   \makecell[l]{XMC1402\\  (Infineon)}                 \\
    \midrule
Architecture in \si{\bit}   
    &   16  &   16  &   32  &   32                                                  \\
Temperature Range in \si{\celsius}  
    &   \numrange{-40}{125}   
            &   \numrange{-40}{150}
                    &   \numrange{-40}{125} 
                            &   \numrange{-40}{125}                                 \\
Voltage range in \si{\volt}         
    &   \numrange{3.0}{3.6} 
            &   \numrange{4.5}{5.5} 
                    &   \numrange{2.7}{5.5} 
                            &   \numrange{2.0}{5.5}                                 \\
CPU speed in \si{\mega\hertz}       
    &   40  &   40  &   upto 112    &   48                                          \\
\makecell[lt]{CPU performance in \si{\celsius}\\ for high temperature} 
    &   $\numrange{-40}{125}= \SI{40}{MIPS}$ 
            &   $\numrange{-40}{150} = \SI{40}{MIPS}$       &   &                   \\
    \addlinespace
I/O pins    
    &   35 pins out of 44 pins 
            &  \makecell[lt]{35 pins out of 44 pins\\ 53 pins out of 64 pins}
                    &       &   \makecell[lt]{35pins out of 48 pins\\ 
                                              48 pins out of 64 pins}               \\
Comparators 
    &   \makecell[lt]{up to 2 analog\\ comparators}
            &   \makecell[lt]{up to 4 analog\\ comparators}
                    &       &   \makecell[lt]{upto 4 analog\\ comparators}          \\
PWM resolution in \si{\nano\second} 
    &   25  &   7.14&       &                                                       \\
\makecell[lt]{Communication\\ Interfaces} 
    &   \makecell[lt]{2 UART modules\\ supports LIN 2.0\\ protocol} 
            &   \makecell[lt]{2 UART modules\\ supports LIN 2.0\\ protocol}
                    &   \makecell[lt]{communication\\ protocol emulation\\ for more LIN} 
                            &   \makecell[lt]{4 interface chanels\\ 
                                              usable as UART\\ and LIN}\\
    \addlinespace
Typical \si{MIPS\per\mega\hertz} 
    &   1   & 1.25  & 0.84   &                                                      \\
Price for QFN-44 
    &       &   $100 = \SI{2.55}{\EUR}$ 
                    &       &   $5\text{k} = \SI{1.46}{\EUR}$                       \\
\phantom{Price for} QFN-64 
    & $100 = \SI{3.86}{\EUR}$ 
            &  $100 = \SI{3.51}{\EUR}$ 
                    &       &   $5\text{k} = \SI{1.92}{\EUR}$                       \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Controller Comparison}
    \label{tab:microproc}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

IN case, that in the documents a bigger fonts are used and in table had to be text with the same font as main text, than seems to sensible to consider change table orientation to landscape. For this seems to be handy package `rotating` and replace `table in above MWE with its`sidewaystable` environment.